# Get value instead of unicode representation from cleaned_data

Tags: django, forms

I want to do some custom validation:

```
class Products(models.Model):
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return "%s Eur %s" %(self.Description, self.Price)

class Orders(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Product = models.ForeignKey(Products, default=None, null=True, blank=True)

class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = Orders
    def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super(OrderForm, self).clean()
            P = cleaned_data.get("Product")
```

The problem I have is that P returns the unicode presentation of Products (like: Cableconnector Eur 6.75) I need however to get the Products id from the cleaned_data. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouch this was really easy....to get the id just call P.id